# belly fat reduction without losing weight

Tags: weight-loss

I have a very lovely body shape and structure but I have belly fat. I have tried doing exercises but I notice I'm reducing in all aspects of my body...my question is that is there anything I can do to reduce my belly fat without reducing in any other part of my body...thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no exercise to target fatburning at a specific area. You have to either accept the bellyfat or loose fat also on other places and redefine those areas by building muscles.

Comment: Additionally, genetics will play a non-negotiable role in where fat is stored the most. You can be bone thin in one area and still have notable fat in another. The only way to get rid of fat in one area is to get rid of fat in all areas, and the only way to do that is to be in a caloric deficit.